# google cloud print on linux

Tags: centos, printing, cloud, g-suite, google-chrome

i'm using `Google apps`, and i would like to use `Google Cloud Print` but all my printers are "classic", and for what i understand it is possible to use a classic printer if i have a running pc with my google account on chrome.
is there any service or something that i can install it on my `CentOS` server so it can be always running and sharing printers too google Cloud Print?

Comment: You may have better luck in superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a python project called [cloudprint](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint/).  It's in the Ubuntu repositories, I don't know about CentOS, check your repos.  Alternatively, you could just download it from Github.  It's fairly straight forward and works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I have that at home. The Printing service for Linux is called CUPS and you can install it in any Linux.

> yum install cups

after that, just browse to `your_centos_ip:631` and add a printer.

After that, i believe you have to login into your google account in that machine and add the printer in google cloud print service.

EDIT: Check here the help from google cloud printing.

> http://support.google.com/cloudprint/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1686197&p=mgmt_classic

Comment: Don't think CUPS interacts with Google Cloud Print.

Comment: No, but google can access the printers. You can add a "Cloud ready printer" and a "Classic Printer". I mention cups, because it's the responsible for printing in Linux. (response edited). I only use Linux and @ home i have this working